# 'worktree' is not a git command

Tags: git

In the source of the OSS project I am working on, there is a script written to create release version from the repository. The script throws an error on this line

```
 git worktree prune
```

The error is :

```
git: 'worktree' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Comment: Have you tried re-installing git?

Comment: what does `git --version` give? Maybe you are using an old git install?

Comment: A quick google search told me that `git worktree` is a new feature in either git `2.x` or `2.5`. It does work on my `2.6.2.windows.1`. Update your git to the latest version and it should work.

Comment: Thanks!! Upgrading to 2.8.3 worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git worktree` is a new-ish feature, experimental in Git version 2.5, more solid in Git 2.6, and with a minor but fairly important fix in 2.7.2 if you move a worktree.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31935776/1256452) for reasons you might want to use `git worktree`.

(already answered in comments, but making a real answer in case others come across this in search)