# Is it possible to have multiple HEADs within a single git repository?

Tags: git

I have cloned a big git repository (about 3.7g) that contains multiple branches. One of the branches is responsible to set up a Windows Installer (InnoSetup) and therefore, after I built the main program, I need to switch to the Installer branch.

Is there a possibility to have a single repository, but two separate HEADs in two different directories, so don't have to clone the repository twice?

Comment: what do you mean? head is referred to a branch, not a repo.

Comment: I dont get why you would have that in one repository. Split it up in two repositories.

Comment: I'm fully aware that the structure is neither useful nor handy. I just came across this situation and was wondering if some kind of multiple heads is possible.

Comment: Git versions at or above 2.5 have `git worktree`, which can make multiple work-trees from a single repository.  Each worktree has its own HEAD and index.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31935776/1256452 (and incidentally, HEAD in Git is shouted :-) —when I read your question my first thought was Mercurial "heads").

Comment: That is exactly, what I was thinking of. I would mark this as correct answer, but it is just a comment.

Comment: @torek Please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your Git is version 2.5 or higher,<sup>1</sup> you have a new command, `git worktree`.  This has an `add` sub-command, which will make a new work-tree in another directory.  Each such work-tree has its own `HEAD` and index (and various state files, such as those used with an in-progress `git am`, `git rebase`, and so on—basically all things reported by `git status`).  See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for details.  Note that even in current versions of Git (2.8.x), `git worktree` is still somewhat experimental.  It should work for this particular use case, though.

See also [What would I use git-worktree for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31935776/1256452)

---

<sup>1</sup>I recommend at least 2.6, which fixes a handful of bugs.  See every mention of "worktree" in [the 2.6.0 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.6.0.txt).