# Best approach to test new stuff in sources without damage anything

Tags: git, github

I was working with Git for a while (not an expert though) and this question never comes to my mind but now is rounding around.

Let's said I have a repository with three branches plus `master`:

- master
- branch_1
- branch_1_devel
- branch_1_devel_test

I am not using `master` at all so `branch_1` becomes and behaves like `master`. Usually and as it should be I make new development at `branch_1_devel` and then I merge those changes when them are ready into `branch_1`.

Now I want to test a new functionality so I have created a new branch `branch_1_devel_test`.  After checkout into that branch I have made changes in a file named `file1`.

Something with more priority needs to be done in `branch_1_devel` so I need to checkout that branch and edit the same `file1`. After all is done I've added the file, commit the changes and then merge into `branch_1`.

Then I go back to `branch_1_devel_test` because I want continue testing where I left in `file1`.

Having this scenario (if you don't understand let me know and I'll try to be more clear) a few questions:

- if I pull the changes from `branch_1_devel` will be `file1` getting into a conflict? meaning I will loose my previous changes?
- do I need to commit the changes made at `branch_1_devel_test` as soon as I checkout into another branch? meaning will be a problem if I try to checkout in a new branch without commit changes in the current one?

The whole idea behind all of this is: I want to test something but I don't want to push changes to `branch_1_devel` neither `branch_1`.

*Update*

This is a small test I have made to understand how Git behaves.

```
$ git branch
  master
  branch_1
* branch_1_devel

$ git checkout -b branch_1_devel_test
Switched to a new branch 'branch1_devel_test'

$ git branch
  master
  branch_1
  branch_1_devel
* branch_1_devel_test
```

Now I am in `branch_1_devel_test` so I have created a new empty file

```
$ git status
# On branch branch_1_devel_test
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   application/controllers/AdminconsoledemoController.php
#
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Switch back to `branch_1_devel`

```
$ git checkout branch_1_devel
Switched to branch 'branch_1_devel'
$ git status
# On branch branch_1_devel
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   application/controllers/AdminconsoledemoController.php
#
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Why if the file was created at `branch_1_devel_test` is being tracked at `branch_1_devel`? That's exactly why I am trying to avoid because I will need to commit the changes before pull anything from origin at `branch_1_devel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly... if you create a file in `branch_1_devel_test` without committing it, it will be independent from the branches (it will not be part of the repo). This means that when you switch back to `branch_1_devel` the file will be still there as an untracked file. If you commit the file in `branch_1_devel_test` the file will be part of the repo and will disappear when you change the branch.

If you want to avoid having the file lying around, you can use the `stash` mechanism. Actually, I am not sure you can stash untracked files. Anyway, what you are trying to do looks weird: if you create a file that is worth keeping, you should commit it. If then, in the future, you will not need it anymore, you can delete it (of course, if it is a large file things are different... )

Comment: I have some issues with stash at some point so for the moment and until I feel more comfortable with it I will use the approach you described before and yes that was exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: Happy to be helpful!

Comment: One more question: what should happen if I delete the branch `branch_1_devel_test`? Will be the file `application/controllers/AdminconsoledemoController.php` also deleted?

Comment: I do not really know where the file belong... :) If it is commited in the branch, then yes...

Comment: Is in the branch I will delete so yes, ok, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) in order to keep development in different branches without `comit`ting or `stash`ing. It allows to checkout branches in their own working directories independently. Example:

```
git worktree add ../project-branch_1 branch_1
```

However `worktree` command has been introduced in Git 2.5 and is still considered experimental:

> Multiple checkout in general is still experimental, and the support
>   for submodules is incomplete. It is NOT recommended to make multiple
>   checkouts of a superproject.

I've never encountered problems with it even with submodules, except for need to manually delete working directories. Other links: [What would I use git-worktree for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31935776/1663197), [github worktree notes](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows).