# Manage multiple git clones on single machine

Tags: git

I have 4 clones of same repository of our project on my system.

The reason for this is that we have evolved in terms of technology stack in past 2 years and each of the 4 versions of this evolution requires a different folder structure & eclipse workspace setup. Each version exists on its own branch. To keep supporting old versions for customers I need to have different clones to ease my work so that I don't have to switch branches and change setup accordingly.

I mostly work offline. So, whenever I connect to network, I execute a script that runs `git fetch` on each of the clones one-by-one. What I want is to save some network bandwidth in this process. I want to run `git fetch` only once on say `prime` repository and rest of the repositories must download the code from `prime`.

I tried setting `prime` as remote to other repositories but it only fetches the locally checked out branches of `prime` in the secondary repositories. Is there at all a way to what I want to achieve?

Comment: Are you using the same branches in each of those repositories, or are those different setups basically permanently set up for different branches?

Comment: @poke I have added my branchwise use-case to the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If each repository has the sole purpose of being there so you have a working directory for one specific (and fixed) branch, then a much better workflow would be to use a single repository with multiple working trees.

So you would only have one repository in which you would have to fetch. Instead of the default one working directory, you would then have a total of four working directories, all using the same repository as its base.

Luckily, Git supports this scenario quite well out of the box with the [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command: Assuming you are inside your “primary” local repository, you can just call `git worktree add` three times to create three more working directories with a specific branch:

```
git worktree add ../legacy-1 legacy-branch-1
git worktree add ../legacy-2 legacy-branch-2
git worktree add ../legacy-3 legacy-branch-3
```

So each of those folders (including the primary one) will be a full and independent working directory with a separate index and everything. It’s just that the underlying repository will be the same and everything will be shared including the remote and its branches. So you can fetch in any of the repositories and all will update (because it’s just a single repository).

There are a few things you need to know when working with multiple working trees. The most important one is that you cannot check out branches that are checked out in worktrees. So each folder should stay fixed to the branch it was initialized for—but I believe that already fits your workflow pretty well anyway.

Comment: thanks for highlighting this great git feature. that's what probably I was looking for. It seems perfect for my use case. I am not sure how exactly it would fit in but I will have to try this out and check, which may be I'll do in a couple of days and get back to you again if required.

Comment: For future readers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935776/what-would-i-use-git-worktree-for

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing things right (I use the same setup with long lived worktrees to avoid switching branches).

To update the currently checked out branch do

```
git pull prime $BRANCH
```

To update the other branches run

```
git fetch prime $B1:$B1 $B2:$B2…
```

Comment: What problem I find here is that `prime` repository must have `$BRANCH` (or `$B1` or `$B2`) locally checked-out at least once with the branch(s) being updated. I cannot directly fetch code from `origin` of `prime` to other repositories, which is what I want.

Comment: My experience is different. I can update `prime` using `git pull origin master` (if `master` is the checked out branch in `prime`) and `git fetch origin $B1:$B1` and then update other worktrees from `prime`. What's your problem fetching/pulling from `prime`?

Comment: I am not yet using worktrees. I wasn't aware of it until I read @poke's answer. I am using multiple clones for which this approach doesn't work.

Comment: I also don't use `git worktree` — my git is not fresh enough. I also use separate clones and the approach works for me fine. In what way it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I get the exception
`fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Of course. For the currently checked out branch you do `git pull prime $BRANCH`, for all other branches `git fetch prime $B1:$B1 $B2:$B2…`