# GIT: How to execute tests in different branch on same system

Tags: git, rspec

I have to perform many tests on a platform and I regularly have to run tests on my local machine.

I use Rspec for testing.

These tests take time and in the meantime, I would like to be able to checkout in another window of my terminal.

Have you ever had to do this? How do you do it?

Comment: Simplest solution: run them on a CI environment. It should also be faster as your local machine could not be as powerful as those envs

Comment: [`git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31935776/7976758)

Comment: Thanks @phd It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: thanks, @DonCallisto but I want to avoid running long CI test. Just want to run the first one my workflow locally (linter, build test app etc...)

Comment: @phd Loved that. Thanks a lot for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your context, you could clone your local repo, get on the branch you want to test on this clone, and run any test you want on this one. Then you would get back to your "original" local and do whatever you want, create other clones for other tests, etc.

Then again, it could be infeasible in your context, for example if your tests involve some global level settings which must be different for different tests.

Comment: Thanks but I want to avoid that behavior. Git worktree is what I was looking for.