# How to keep changes if I want to checkout to another branch but I don't want to commit yet?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-checkout

Let's say I'm on branch A and I do some changes on the branch. For some reason, I need to check out to branch B But the problem is I don't wanna commit them yet. I just wanna keep them without committing them.
I already tried stashing using `git add .` and then  `git stash`. But I'm not sure if I do it right because after I run `git taste`. it automatically removes my changes. and when I switch to another branch and then switch back to that branch, all the changes disappeared.
what should I do in this situation? Any advice?

Comment: `git worktree` is one of the options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935776/what-would-i-use-git-worktree-for

Comment: "I don't wanna commit them yet" -> Why? A local commit can't break anything. Just commit without pushing. When you'll resume work on branch A, just undo the commit while keeping changes in place with `git reset HEAD^`. Of course, stashing somewhat automates this, but stash entries come and go... a temp commit stays on its relevant branch.

Comment: You can have a look at `--include-untracked` and `--keep-index` options to `git stash` command. Also, use `git stash` to save changes and `git stash pop` to apply them back.

Comment: What is `git taste` above? Presumably it is some alias you have for some other Git command...?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to pop the stash - It doesn't automatically get applied to the branch after you check it out.

Use something like `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`

[See the documentation for git stash.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer committing to stashing, before fiddling with working tree/cache (unless you use [`git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) to compare another branch content in another folder).

Once your status is clean (you have committed your work in progress), you can *[restore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)* ([`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)) files from another branch to have a look:

```
git restore --source <anotherCommit> -- .
# once you are done
git restore -- . # restore HEAD content
```