# Manage multiple branches

Tags: git, git-branch

1. When I started to code I had two branches Main and PopUp.
2. I was working in the PopUp branch but I had to stop because I need to work in another feature.
3. In order to work in this new feature I create another branch called Form.
4. I finished the work in Form branch and I also merged in to the main branch, after that I delete this branch.
5. Now I am continuing working in the PopUp branch but I cannot see the changes that was implemented by the Form branch.
6. When I move to the main branch I can see the changes implemented by the Form branch.
7. But when i move again to the PopUp branch I cannot see this changes.

Could you please help me in order to see this changes from the PopUp branch but I dont want to lose the work that I have in the Pop Up branch.

The changes made in the form branch are totally separate (another section in HTML, here I also create a separate JS file and also a separate CSS file ) that the work that I am doing in the popUp branch but I would like to see the changes.

Thanks
Happy coding ;)

When I move to the PopUp branch and check it with git status told me that is uptodate.
I use terminal to interact with github.

Comment: Get a _good_ git GUI that shows you concurrent branches, like GitKraken or SourceTree. I believe it's too hard to visualize or understand git branching, stashes, work-trees and the like using only stock in-box `git` tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Git provides a nice, albeit under-appreciated, solution to this problem: you can create secondary "work trees" for your repository, each with a different checked-out branch.

See the ['worktree' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-worktree) and in particular [What would I use git-worktree for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31935776/2954547) for good descriptions and discussions on this topic.

This is a legitimate use case and it comes up all the time. The typical recommendation is to use `git stash` in order to switch from working on one task to the other, but I find this incredibly disruptive. Having multiple Git worktrees has been a lifesaver many times when I was in the middle of working on something, and I needed to switch branches for a quick bugfix.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem when  I return to the popUp branch I merge this branch with the main branch. Thanks

[Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai)
[shadowtalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954547/shadowtalker)