# Comparing master against another branch in Git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff

I know that I can use this

```
git diff master..feature_branch
```

Which will output *all differences* between those two branches.

---

Now, my question is, how can I get only the differences coming from `feature_branch`.

In other words, I want to know

*What does `feature_branch` would **add** to `master` if I were to merge them ?*

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [git diff to see what a merge would introduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727102/), but on the other hand there is no accepted answer to the dupe target. But these two threads should probably be joined once(/if) you get a satisfactory answer to this question.

Comment: @dfri Thanks for the link. What is the good practice when things like that happens ? Should I wait for an answer  or this should be closed as dupe?

Comment: I honestly don't know what would be the best practice, but I would wait for an answer before linking this (or the other) one. Even if I as OP found an other older thread myself but didn't find the single (non-accepted) answer satisfactory, I would consider opening a new thread and explicitly pointing our that there is no satisfactory answer in the previously asked question. Anyway, you might want to try out the [triple dot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17617690/4573247) approach, and if it works, answer this question yourself (and then we'll attempt to close the other one pointing at this one).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git diff to see what a merge would introduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727102/git-diff-to-see-what-a-merge-would-introduce)

Comment: @dfri Thanks for that. it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a meta post about this, but it seems like the right thing is (or would be) to ask and answer, then close the *other* question as a duplicate of the *newer* one, if the other question won't ever get an answer chosen...

Comment: @torek This is kind of a really interesting situation, because I'm the author of a thread that is somewhat similar to what you're suggesting. I think by editing it we could really underline a specific problem that we would need to address. Have a look at the [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371293/7692463). I could potentially write another thread also.

Comment: I suggest that, once you can accept your own answer, we follow @torek's advice and close the older question (that I linked to above) as a duplicate _to_ this one. As torek is a gold badge user of `git` tag, he should be able to single-handedly perform this dupe link.

Comment: @torek I actually opened a [thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371891/7692463) on meta since I want to know I think this situation is interesting.

Comment: @dfri Let's see what people think at meta before.

Answer (score 2):

The *triple dot notation* solved it for me, since it basically compares the second branch relatively to the first one.

```
git diff master...feature_branch
```

Note though that **this will only work for committed changes**.

---

If ever you're like me and you're actually cleaning your branches and was wondering how to check if it had potential un-merged content, I highly recommend using

```
git branch -d feature_branch
```

Note the `-d` (lowercase flag). By passing that if ever you have un-merged content you will receive this kind of message

```
error: The branch 'feature_branch' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D feature_branch'.
```

Comment: This (`git diff master...feature`) is usually the way to go. There's a minor bug in Git where, if there is more than one merge base, the triple-dot notation misfires here. You can tell if this has occurred if you know how to spot a combined diff.