# What is the git diff command needed to show the changes a merge would make without performing the merge?

Tags: git

*What is the `git diff` command needed to show the changes a merge would make without performing the merge?*

I've done searches and not found what I'm looking for.  For example, I'm on branch `feature/cool`, and I run `git diff main`.  It shows me all of the new files I have created on `feature/cool` **that's not what would be merged**.  It is, however, a valid difference between the two branches.

I've seen how to do this with `git merge` see this:

- This [git diff to see what a merge would introduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727102/git-diff-to-see-what-a-merge-would-introduce) is the same/similar question but the answer is to use git merge.

I would accept that git doesn't have a way to do that with the `git diff` command but *I thought* I found the command to do this a few days ago.

Comment: There might be a `git log` command that does this.

Comment: Well.... `git diff main` will show you what would be merged _if `main`_ has not moved since you started working on your branch (or you last merged it). If the branch moved, you need to use `...`: `git diff main...` (3 dots) or `git diff main...@` (or something like that).

Comment: It’s unclear to me what this means. A merge is visualized as a three-way, diff, while `git diff` as used here is two-way.

Comment: (note: still not a single command, but a possible alternative of `git merge -n`) If your intention is to be able to preview the diff without modifying your index or your files on disk, there is `git merge-tree` ([doc here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree)). After calling it you may compare the content of the tree that was generated to either side of the merge: `git diff main <tree-id>` or `git diff branch <tree-id>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to know before the merge, *exactly* what will change after the merge, **in all scenarios**. That being said, most of the time the [3 dot diff syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69559520/184546) will be close:

```
git diff <target-branch>...<source-branch>
```

The 3 dot diff will be exactly correct in either of the following scenarios:

1. The source branch is fully up to date with the target branch.
2. The source branch doesn't touch any of the same files as the target branch, since the merge-base of the two branches.

When those 2 rules aren't true, it's possible that the same lines have been modified on both sides (oftentimes due to a cherry-pick) and then some of the changes that show up in the diff won't actually be included in the merge.

**Side Note:** The 3 dot diff, being useful most of the time, is oftentimes used as the default view for Pull Requests in some tools (e.g. GitHub and Azure DevOps).

**Suggestion:** If you really want to know what will change, just do it and look:

```
git switch --detach <target-branch> # detach to avoid touching existing branches
git merge <source-branch> --no-ff # force a merge commit to prevent fast-forward
git diff @~1 @ # look at the difference between before and after the merge commit
```